# How can I get rid of extra "Photo Stream" album on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-id, photo-stream

On my iPhone (and iPad) I have "Photo Stream" enabled for my primary Apple ID (I have others setup for mail, etc).

On my iPad it works fine - I see the one "Photo Stream" button and everything shows up there.

On my iPhone (iPhone 4) there are two "Photo Stream" albums for some reason. One is the correct one with my pictures, and one is blank and when I go into it there is just the message that explains what the stream is and says "No Photos".

If I disable "Photo Stream" temporarily on the phone the album disappears with my pictures, but the blank album remains.

How can I get rid of this blank album?

Comment: While this may not actually answer your question, I just did the same thing and it worked, but my issue was slightly different. I had one iCloud account, then moved my MobileMe account, and set that one up instead. Turning off photostream and then starting it again removed the 'extra' album left over from my first iCloud account.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can ! You have to turn it back on, take a picture and wait for it to upload to iCloud. Then you turn it off and and confirm the warning that says that all the pictures will be deleted. The album will then disappear.